# SQL Server : how can I order data in the same column to be ascending for some data and descending for other data?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by, case

I am new to both SQL and stack exchange so please bear with me. For this problem, I have two columns that I need to sort in a very specific way.

Data sample and desired order shown below:

[image: Data]

What I need to accomplish is sorting the data first by sector into three distinct sets

```
1: 1D, 1E, 1F 
2: 2D, 2E, 2F
3: 3D, 3E
```

Then, each of these sets needs to be sorted in the following way:

Set 1 is sorted by sector and aisle in ascending order

And set 2 and 3 are sorted by sector and aisle in descending order

I have been able to accomplish these two ordering systems but I have not been able to combine them in a way that works. My biggest question is this, how can I order some of the rows (1D-1F) by aisle in ascending order while others (2D-3E) are ordered in descending order as shown?

[image: Data]

Comment: Sets should be 1: 1D, 1E, 1F      2: 2D, 2E, 2F      3: 3D, 3E

Comment: Does your column always has only a number and a char?

Comment: Yes, the sector column always consists of one number and one character

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a couple of CASEs.  I just hope the table is small otherwise the performance could be horrible.  Consider to add an extra column "SortOrder" to your table and to use this instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM #mytable
ORDER BY LEFT(sector,1) ASC,
CASE WHEN sector like '1%' THEN RIGHT(sector,1) END ASC,
CASE WHEN sector like '1%' THEN aisle END ASC,
CASE WHEN sector not like '1%' THEN RIGHT(sector,1)  END DESC,
CASE WHEN sector not like '1%' THEN aisle END DESC
```

Comment: That has some promise but the table is massive, 22 columns by 36,000+ rows